# Sanitize log via Logstash filter

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I'm new to logstash and would like to see if anyone could help with parsing my application log, which looks like this (Changed the api key with random characters):

> 2019-07-17 16:57:20,522 : braze INFO: Body: {"attributes":
>   [{"external_id": "vT9fswqW", "email": "aaa@yahoo.com", "site":
>   "site"}], "api_key": "fg09831e-9re0-tc19-81c6-08934539f0vx2", "events":
>   [{"properties": {"site": "site"}, "external_id": "vT9fswqW", "name":
>   "REGISTER", "time": "2019-07-17'+0'16:57:20.522380"}]}

This log goes to logstash where filters can be applied before storing the log in ES. I would like to sanitize this log to hide certain information, like the email, external_id and api_key, so the final output from logstash would be something like:

> 2019-07-17 16:57:20,522 : braze INFO: Body: {"attributes":
>   [{"external_id": "****", "email": "****", "site":
>   "site"}], "api_key": "fg09831e-****", "events":
>   [{"properties": {"site": "site"}, "external_id": "****", "name":
>   "REGISTER", "time": "2019-07-17'+0'16:57:20.522380"}]}

The part starting with `{"attributes"...` is a valid JSON, so I was thinking if I can store that part of the log in a separate field, I could then apply the `json` logstash filter and then mutate the fields. I'm trying to separate the log to get the json only, but all my attempts using grok are failing. Any ideas how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it using

```
    grok { match => { "message" => "Body: %{GREEDYDATA:[@metadata][json]}" } }
    json {
        source => "[@metadata][json]"
        remove_field => [ "[api_key]", "[attributes][0][email]", "[attributes][0][external_id]", "[events][0][external_id]" ]
    }
```

To parse the first part of the message I would use dissect rather than grok.

Comment: Thanks, @Badger, that did help to resolve my problem!